# Python-way of getting a substring with a specified delimiter?

Tags: python, io

Under a certain directory, I have a bunch of files with the name format:

> userName_description

How may I extract the `userName` out?
What about extracting the `description` out?

I am wishing for a nice "Pythonic" way of achieving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name.split("_")` creates a list splitting string by the argument.

```
username = name.split("_")[0]
description = name.split("_")[1]
```

Comment: There's no need to split twice. Just unpack the sequence into the `username, description` tuple: `username, description = name.split('_')`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `glob` module:

```
import glob

for filename in glob.iglob('*_*'):
    username, description = filename.split('_')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `split` method takes an optional separator character and returns a list. See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split)

```
words = name.split('_')
username = words[0]
description = words[1]
```